# What is the hidden character in this string?

Tags: string, unicode, character-encoding

I'm parsing a string from a news feed, and I'm getting some strange behavior on my app. I've been looking more close to this feed and I found some hidden characters in it. Here it's an example taken from that feed:

"das empresas portuguesas neste país"

After the word "portuguesas" seems to be some character there. How can I find what char is it so I can manage to remove them?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: seems that copy/pasting text here just removed it. Can this be encoding-related?

Comment: are they escaped characters? an ASCII code or unicode number might help

Comment: It's a space. Look for the biggest key on your keyboard.

Comment: If it's a hidden character, how is posting it on a webpage going to help?

Comment: Show us some code -- can't solve a problem without seeing the code.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: what language / tools are you using for parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Portuguese, the name of the language itself is ‘português’, where that ‘ê’ can be expressed in Unicode as either code point U+EA, which is LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX, or as a regular ‘e’ followed by code point U+301, COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT. So the string might be 9 but it might be 10 characters long.  The longer form is in Normalization Form D (formed by canonical decomposition) and the shorter one is in NFC (formed by canonical decomposition *followed* by canonical composition).

However, when the word is inflected, the diacritic is lost, so words like ‘portuguesas’, which concords in number and gender with the noun ‘empresas’, should not bear any diacritics at all.

The string you sent has only a single non-ASCII character in it, and it is a printing one. It’s in the word ‘país’.

This shows each logical code point of UTF-8 input:

```
$ echo "das empresas portuguesas neste país" | perl -CS -ne 'printf "%v02X\n", $_'
64.61.73.20.65.6D.70.72.65.73.61.73.20.70.6F.72.74.75.67.75.65.73.61.73.20.6E.65.73.74.65.20.70.61.ED.73.0A
```

And this shows each separate byte of it:

```
$ echo "das empresas portuguesas neste país" | perl -C0 -ne 'printf "%v02X\n", $_'
64.61.73.20.65.6D.70.72.65.73.61.73.20.70.6F.72.74.75.67.75.65.73.61.73.20.6E.65.73.74.65.20.70.61.C3.AD.73.0A
```

Here is how to do that if you only want to see the non-ASCII code points:

```
# logical code points
$ echo "das empresas portuguesas neste país" | perl -CS -pe 's/[^\x00-\x7F]/sprintf "\x5Cx{%X}", ord $&/ge'
das empresas portuguesas neste pa\x{ED}s

# separate bytes
$ echo "das empresas portuguesas neste país" | perl -C0 -pe 's/[^\x00-\x7F]/sprintf "\x5Cx%X", ord $&/ge'
das empresas portuguesas neste pa\xC3\xADs
```

That ‘í’ could be code point U+ED, or it might be regular ‘i’ followed by code point U+301, COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT. If so, it would show up like this:

```
# show the NFD form
$ perl -CS -le 'print "das empresas portuguesas neste pai\x{301}s"'                                                     
das empresas portuguesas neste país

# show UTF-8 non-ASCII code points
$ perl -CS -le 'print "das empresas portuguesas neste pai\x{301}s"' | perl -CS -pe 's/[^\x00-\x7F]/sprintf "\x5Cx{%X}", ord $&/ge'
das empresas portuguesas neste pai\x{301}s

# show non-ASCII bytes
$ perl -CS -le 'print "das empresas portuguesas neste pai\x{301}s"' | perl -C0 -pe 's/[^\x00-\x7F]/sprintf "\x5Cx%X", ord $&/ge'
das empresas portuguesas neste pai\xCC\x81s
```

It may be that Stack Overflow (or something else) rewrote your string, possibly deleting nonprinting characters. So you might have stuff in there that we can’t see because it isn’t in the data we looked at.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "das empresas portuguesas neste país" | od -b 
0000000 144 141 163 040 145 155 160 162 145 163 141 163 040 160 157 162
0000020 164 165 147 165 145 163 141 163 040 156 145 163 164 145 040 160
0000040 141 303 255 163 012
0000045
```

I can see no hidden characters in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If it comes from a rss downloaded from here:
http://feeds.feedburner.com/PublicoEconomia?format=xml
they use three-byte UTF-8 chars for puntuation (in particular: U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, UTF-8: 0xE2 0x80 0x9D, should be the character right after "portuguesas"). You are probably eating the first byte in your code.